# Google Sheets LOOKUP unable to find lookup value even if there is

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

```
=lookup(A4,'LTO Renewal Record'!B2:B20,'LTO Renewal Record'!C2:C20)
```

Above code is suppose to return a date value. However, it gives me an error saying "Did not find value "my value" in LOOKUP evaluation." even though it is there.

Here's a link of the [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TDPWPLQPyvH6OiL8wIOSP5XvoxjfZDvBJMTYiF4WrIs/edit?usp=sharing) I'm trying to work on.

What I would like to do here is to lookup the latest value it can find on the column, and add 1 year to it since I am trying to track the expiration date of the vehicle's registration.

This is my code in MS Excel VBA when adding one year to the lookup value:

```
.Range("R" & MatchRow + 13).Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, TextBox2.Value)
```

However, I haven't the faintest idea how to have this working on Google Sheet, I've tried researching online but unable to find what I'm looking for. Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=TEXT(DATE(YEAR(VLOOKUP(A4, SORT('LTO Renewal Record'!B2:C20, 2, 0), 2, 0))+1, 
          MONTH(VLOOKUP(A4, SORT('LTO Renewal Record'!B2:C20, 2, 0), 2, 0)), 
            DAY(VLOOKUP(A4, SORT('LTO Renewal Record'!B2:C20, 2, 0), 2, 0))), 
 "mmm dd, yyyy")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(TEXT(
 DATE(YEAR(VLOOKUP(A4:A, SORT('LTO Renewal Record'!B2:C20, 2, 0), 2, 0))+1, 
     MONTH(VLOOKUP(A4:A, SORT('LTO Renewal Record'!B2:C20, 2, 0), 2, 0)), 
       DAY(VLOOKUP(A4:A, SORT('LTO Renewal Record'!B2:C20, 2, 0), 2, 0))), "mmm dd, yyyy")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`LOOKUP` only works if the data is sorted. See documentation here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570?hl=en

In this case, I would suggest using something like `VLOOKUP`. Try this: `=vlookup(A4,'LTO Renewal Record'!$B$2:$C$20,2,)`. (I added the `$` to lock the references, in case you need to copy/paste it around.) You can see the documentation for `VLOOKUP` here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en

Comment: I did try VLOOKUP first, however, it gets the first match it can retrieve. I have multiple results for my lookup value, and as per my question, I would like to get the latest added data.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the misread. I missed that detail. Would it be possible to add helper columns to your data table `LTO Renewal Record`? I think if you don't mind doing that, you can do a `COUNTIF` and do a multiple-criteria `VLOOKUP` (or `INDEX`/`MATCH` to search for the highest-valued `COUNTIF`).

Comment: I made an example of how such a solution would be laid out for your data set here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12ZoHvflFAH6V_XUoO7sJYdVe2yINV8uWckW9HkOzBE4